# How do I transfer a Blender VSE project to another computer?

Tags: edit-mode, video

I started working on a project in blender video editor. I transferred the original MP4 file onto my flash drive and the blender file onto the flash drive. I then transfer and download both files to the new computer and although in the editor it shows all my changes but I can't see the video only a grey screen and I can't hear any audio. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Could it be that you didn't transfer all the other files (audio and texture) and only transfered the .blend file?

Comment: Is it possible that the relative locations that were set up on the original .blend are not the same as on the other computer?  Either way, you should be able to re-link your file paths on the other computer to get it working for now.

Answer (score 2):

Before transferring, make sure the paths to external files are relative. You can make all paths relative through the File > External Data menu. Then save the blend file. Now you can copy the files, and open the blend file at the new location.